# ckeditor 4 loading custom toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

If I use: `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { toolbar: 'Full' }); <br/>`
I get my custom toolbar, but no text on the page
If I use: `CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', { toolbar: 'Full' });<br/>`
I get my text but not the full custom toolbar, 
I don't get the Source button 
Button definition...

```
> config.toolbar_Full = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   items: ['Source','Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },<br/>
        { name: 'editing',     items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll'] },<br/>
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },<br/>
        { name: 'links',  items: ['Link', 'Unlink'] },<br/>
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'] },<br/>
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize'] },<br/>
        { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] }<br/>
    ];<br/>
```

I have also tried adding it like this:  `{ name: 'document',    items: ['Source'] }`, rest of toolbar.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get the Source button

Because the Source button does not work with the inline editor. You can use the [sourcedialog](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog) plugin instead (see samples here – http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sourcearea.html).

Comment: I have that in the config.js file  <br/> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
   config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog';

    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.disableObjectResizing = true;
    config.toolbar_Full = [

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: I want to have Source editing with my inline editor, I've added sourcedialog via the config.js file, but I can't get the source button and my text at the same time. I must be missing something, what? I can't see from the sample page what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please read [Installing plugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins) to make sure that you did all the steps. And remember that you need to add `'Sourcedialog'` button to your toolbar configuration. Note the difference in button names.

Comment: Ah thank you, nowhere have I seen that button name. So is the button name always the same as any plugin name?

Comment: It depends – there's no rule for that. BTW. Since CKEditor 4.5.0 there will be a toolbar configurator available in each CKEditor package. There's a beta version already that you can check here – http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/ckeditor/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html